# Using Not Equal in ArcPy SetNull

Tags: arcpy, error-010416

I am trying to set all values in my raster that are not equal to -9999 to Null using Arcpy.
The problem is that using `!=` operator gets me:

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010416: Error in setting raster table filter for F:\Data\test.tif.

However, other operators like `=` or `<` works okay.

Any ideas?

---

I solved the problem using `<>` instead of `!=`, but I still do not understand why ArcGIS Desktop and ArcPy use different operators for the same functions.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/Data"

# check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inRaster = arcpy.Raster('test.tif')
outSetNull = arcpy.sa.SetNull(inRaster, in_false_raster_or_constant=1, where_clause='Value != -9999')
```

Comment: Have you tried to use not equal <>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!=` is Python syntax for `does not equal`. `<>` is sql syntax for the same. Since the expression in question is an sql where clause, you must use the sql syntax, even though it’s within a python script.

`<` and `=` perform the same function in sql and python (edit: python uses `==` for equals), which is why python syntax seems to ‘work’ in your sql where clause.